# How to implement custom filter in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There are lots of link I found for reference. But unfortunately they didn't worked for me. So I am posting here. Issue is my control is not hitting the "OnActionExecuting". This is the first time I am working with WebAPI and I guess I am missing something somewhere. Please HELP!!

My API filter looks like this:

```
public class ValidateCustomAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{        

    public new void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {            
        //removed for Breviety
    }
    public void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionExecutedContext request)
    {
        //removed for Breviety
    }

}
```

I registered my filter on Startup.cs:

```
public class StartUp : System.Web.HttpApplication
{        
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //removed for Breveity
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateCustomAntiForgeryTokenAttribute());
    }
}
```

And using it on one of my controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
[ValidateCustomAntiForgeryToken]
public class QuestionController : ApiController
{
}
```

Comment: And you know you are making it past your CustomAuthorize Attribute?

Comment: @AndrewHunter I noticed that now. I wish I could give that a try now. But at home I dont have access to my TFS. Will give a try by removing CustomAuthorize tomorrow. You think that could be the cause?

Comment: @AlishaChaitali could be, yup.  Nothing looks immediately wrong.  If you can, make sure that `CustomAuthorize` is working as expected.  If it's acting funny, give [this Authentication filters article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters) a look.  I'm assuming it's an authorization filter, and if it's set up as a normal ActionFilter I'd think that you'd see some issues due to filter execution order.

Comment: @JosephRT thanks for info.. will let you know tomorrow

Comment: Also, try replacing `new` with `override`. `ActionFilterAttribute` defines those two as `virtual` so you can override them. It could be that they just not hit because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext request)
{
    //removed for Breviety
}
```

*OnActionExecuting* expects parameter ***HttpActionContext***